# In a Swagger YAML definition, is there a way to avoid duplication among HTTP methods?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am writing an API spec for which I want the PUT and PATCH functionality to be identical. It won't matter whether the API receives a PUT or a PATCH request. It will do the same thing.

Is there a shorthand/reference syntax for this that would prevent me from copying and pasting the parameters and responses, etc. from my PUT method definition to the PATCH method definition?

Comment: short answer, no. You cannot have an operation with two methods. Technically, you can, but you will not be able to execute them from the ui, so you will have to modify swagger ui, which is not advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Although the OpenAPI (fka Swagger) Specification 2.0 supports `$ref` in some places of an API definition, it's not supported on the operation level. So you need to have separate definitions for PUT and PATCH. You can reduce the code duplication somewhat by `$ref`ing parameters and responses within each operation.

```
paths:
  /foo:
    # If ALL operations within a path have some common parameters,
    # define these params on the path level instead
    # parameters:
    #  - $ref: '#/parameters/baz'

    put:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/baz'
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: '#/responses/Success'
        default:
          $ref: '#/responses/Error'
    patch:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/baz'
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: '#/responses/Success'
        default:
          $ref: '#/responses/Error'

parameters:
  baz:
    in: query
    name: baz
    type: string

responses:
  Success:
    description: Operation completed successfully
    schema:
      type: object
      ...
  Error:
    description: Error response
    schema:
      type: object
      ...
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Better than nothing!